# install Datatable from datatables.net in php

Tags: php, datatable

I am trying to install DataTable into my php code, I had already link the two CDN into my nav-bar but it wouldn't work. There's three errors in console:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at tables.php:279
(anonymous) @ tables.php:279
Chart.min.js:7 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Qe.construct (Chart.min.js:7)
    at new Qe (Chart.min.js:7)
    at chart-area-demo.js:32
acquireContext @ Chart.min.js:7
construct @ Chart.min.js:7
Qe @ Chart.min.js:7
(anonymous) @ chart-area-demo.js:32
Chart.min.js:7 

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
    at Object.acquireContext (Chart.min.js:7)
    at Qe.construct (Chart.min.js:7)
    at new Qe (Chart.min.js:7)
    at chart-pie-demo.js:7
```

which reference to this line of code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
```

do anyone know how to fix it?

```
enter code here

<?php
include 'Nav-bar-upper.php';
?>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#dataTable').DataTable();
} );
</script>

  <!-- DataTales Example -->
  <div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
      <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold text-primary">DataTables Example</h6>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <div class="table-responsive">
        <table id="dataTable" class="table table-bordered "  width="100%" cellspacing="0">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Position</th>
              <th>Office</th>
              <th>Age</th>
              <th>Start date</th>
              <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

 </div>

 <?php
 include 'Nav-bar-lower.php';
 ?>
```

//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css

code from Nav-bar-upper.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Expenses Tracker</title>


  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/input.css">

  <!-- Table CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
```

code from Nav-bar-lower.php:

```
<!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<!-- Core plugin JavaScript-->
<script src="vendor/jquery-easing/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom scripts for all pages-->
<script src="js/sb-admin-2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level plugins -->
<script src="vendor/chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>

<!-- Page level custom scripts -->
<script src="js/demo/chart-area-demo.js"></script>
<script src="js/demo/chart-pie-demo.js"></script>

<!-- Font Awesome Icons -->
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/b6676a21ac.js"></script>

<!-- Manual Input -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Table CDN -->
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You should show us your code in Nav-bar-upper.php. You may have not included the JQuery itself which is a requirement in using Datatables.

Comment: @RayCaballero I just edited the post to include those code.

Comment: You have to load jQuery **before** you try to use it, not afterwards.

Comment: @Quentin I have edited the code as told, it still didn't work, is it something about javascript in php?

Answer (score 0):

As already said, if you want to use jQuery you need to include it before you use it.
In your example it would mean that you include jQuery in your `Nav-bar-upper.php`, next to your stylesheets:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="author" content="">

  <title>Expenses Tracker</title>


  <!-- Custom fonts for this template-->
  <link href="vendor/fontawesome-free/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i" rel="stylesheet">

  <!-- Custom styles for this template-->
  <link href="css/sb-admin-2.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

  
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/input.css">

  <!-- Table CDN -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.21/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
  
 <!-- jQuery CDN -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have edited the code as you told, it still didn't work :(

Comment: So, I extract from the error message that it says that the $ symbol is not defined when using jQuery and that only can happen if you use jQuery before including it, so whatever it is, try to include jQuery above the code you wrote.